# I am not able to understand Scanner or I should say the inputs from console

Tags: java, console

I am not able to understand Scanner or I should say the inputs from console

```
public class Calculate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("enter the lines");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
         String line = "";
         while((line = s.nextLine()) != null) {
             result.add(line);
         }
         for(String ss : result){
             System.out.println(ss);
         }
    }
}

Console :
enter the lines
[Inputs on console:]
aa
bb
cc
```

When I run in debug mode, the string aa and bb are added to List result, but when cc is read from scanner, it is not added to List
I am not sure, what I am missing. looks silly to me, but some how I am not able to think what I am missing

Comment: agree, this is sort of stupid question, but I am not able to think :(

Comment: Your code should not print anything as the `while` loop will not exit (you can't enter `null` in the console)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (slightly) amended code works as expected (you can exit the program by entering an empty string):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("enter the lines");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = s.nextLine()) != null) {
        if (line.isEmpty()) break;
        result.add(line);
    }
    for (String ss : result) {
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
}
```

It outputs exactly what is inputed.

Comment: I would use the `hasNextLine()` method in the loop rather than reading the line directly, that way you get slightly neater syntax.

Comment: @BoristheSpider or simply: `while(true) { line = s.nextLine();...` because `hasNextLine` will always return true with the console.

Comment: @Naroji Did you enter `aa <ENTER> bb <ENTER> cc <ENTER> <ENTER>`?

Comment: thanks, I not put the last <ENTER>, done it and now its working. but why we need to put the last enter > to make EOF

Comment: @Naroji you need a way to exit the `while` loop. In your code there was nothing so the program never got to print anything. I added: `if (line.isEmpty()) break;` to exit the while loop when the user enters an empty line. You can change that to anything you want but there needs to be something otherwise the program has no way to know when you are done entering inputs...